# Can you use a function with optional arguments for pipelining in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, default-value, named-parameters

I try this (using Core):

```ml
    Some 9 
      |> Option.value_exn 
      |> printf "%d\n"
```

But the interpreter says:

```
Line 2, characters 9-25:
Error: This expression has type
         ?here:Base__Source_code_position0.t ->
         ?error:Base.Error.t -> ?message:string -> 'a option -> 'a
       but an expression was expected of type int option -> 'b
```

"This expression" here refers to `Option.value_exn`.

Is it impossible to use a function like `value_exn` that has named parameter with default values, pipelining in the single non-named parameter, without manually specifying all the named parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use [ppx_pipebang](https://github.com/janestreet/ppx_pipebang)

This will transform `f |> g` into `g (f)` and make your expression compile. It also allows you to use constructors in a pipeline even though they are not functions, e.g.

```
x |> Some
```

If you’re going to use a lot of core, I would recommend using all of [ppx_jane](https://github.com/janestreet/ppx_jane) to get other things like various `[@deriving ...]` transformations which give you for free many functions required by functors in Core.

If you are using [dune](https://dune.build) to build your project (I believe this is now the standard for new projects), you can add this to your `dune` file (taken straight from the documentation of dune):

```
(executable
 (name hello_world)
 (libraries core)
 (preprocess (pps ppx_jane)))
```